# SQL Server LIKE with square brackets works directly but not using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I am using square brackets in the like to indicate a range of wildcard characters.
The weird thing is that using the expression directly in the statement works correctly, fetching the expected rows. But using the same expression from a variable does not bring any results.
Why doesn't it work from the variable?

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE Column LIKE '%B[A-Z][A-Z]%';
Results: BAA, BAB, BAC, ... until BZZ
```

Does'n work:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(10)
SET @var = N'B[A-Z][A-Z]'
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE Column LIKE CONCAT('%', @var, '%');
```

I also tried concatenating with + but still getting zero results (LIKE '%' + @var + '%')

The same expression works when I use only one range in the variable, but I really need to use two ranges

```
SET @var = N'B[A-Z]'
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE Column LIKE '%' + @var + '%';
Results: BA, BB, BC, BD, ....
```

Comment: Your code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81ec780dbea9ab737a17eae7041f1ce4.

Comment: Your variable isn't long enough for the pattern, so it's truncated

Comment: Thansk @cf_en. That was the problem! I don't understand why the Management Studio didn't notify the truncation

Comment: Because it's documented that it truncates the value, @2k.silvio . From [Converting Character Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#_character): *"When character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated."* You're converting a `varchar(11)` to a `varchar(10)`, and thus the value is truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your variable longer so that it can store the whole pattern. You can see what value the variable actually has with `PRINT @var`, which will show you the closing square bracket has been dropped.

```
declare @var varchar(10) = 'B[A-Z][A-Z]'
print @var
```